# Create a DataFrame from present Dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

I have a dataframe as given below.

```
data = {'Participant':['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
    'Total test Result':[1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
    'result' : ['negative', 'negative', 'negative', 'negative', 'negative', 'negative', 'negative', 'negative', 'negative', 'negative', ], 
    'time': ['2021-06-14', '2021-06-21', '2021-06-24', '2021-06-28', '2021-07-01', '2021-07-05', '2021-07-08', '2021-06-17', '2021-06-17', '2021-06-20'] }
pres_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pres_df
```

Note: 'time' column is in DateTime format if it helps.

[image]

I want to create a new dataframe in which the multiple values of 'Participant' are consolidated to 1 row with the creation of multiple rows of time and result.
The required final result is given below as in how it should look.

[image]
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.pivot_table`:

```
df.rename(columns={'time':'date'},inplace=True)
df = df.assign(test_res = 'Test' + df.groupby('Participant').cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['Participant','Total test Result'], 
                                      columns=['test_res'],
                                      values=['date','result'],
                                      aggfunc = 'first'
                                      )
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f"{x[1]}_{x[0]}" if ('Test' in x[1]) else x[0])
df1 = df1[sorted(df1.columns)].reset_index()
```

**df1:**
[image]

Comment: This doesn't make it because for Participant 'A', for the first test, the result is 'negative'. In this case its 'NaN'. I think its taking the values randomly, I am not sure.

Comment: @shivakumar:  oops sorry the issue was with the `df1.columns = sorted(df1.columns)`

Comment: @shivakumar: Actually I made blunder. I was trying to sort the columns but instead rename the columns. That's why you saw `NaN` which was part of `date` column not the `result`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = pres_df.groupby("Participant", as_index=False).agg(
    {"Total test Result": "first", "result": list, "time": list}
)

a = x.pop("result").apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(
        x, index=[f"test{v}_Result" for v in range(1, len(x) + 1)]
    )
)
b = x.pop("time").apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(
        x, index=[f"test{v}_date" for v in range(1, len(x) + 1)]
    )
)

out = pd.concat([x, a, b], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  Participant  Total test Result test1_Result  test1_date test2_Result  test2_date test3_Result  test3_date test4_Result  test4_date
0           A                  1     negative  2021-06-14          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN
1           B                  4     negative  2021-06-21     negative  2021-06-24     negative  2021-06-28     negative  2021-07-01
2           C                  2     negative  2021-07-05     negative  2021-07-08          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN
3           D                  3     negative  2021-06-17     negative  2021-06-17     negative  2021-06-20          NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Working perfectly well. Thanks a lot!. This is some usage of pandas, pop and Series function.